# Clicking Update Button Wipes Out the Code

Tags: templates

Has anyone encountered that? When I click "Update" button on "Edit Template" page, all the code that the template contained is mysteriously gone. The browser shows blank page.

What happens? How to prevent that?

Comment: Having the same issue, did you fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like an addon is getting in the way or your EE install is off somehow. Try disabling Extensions and check for JS errors. You might need to reupload your CP theme as well.

Answer (score 0):

Could be that your host has ran out of Disk Space, the same happened to us and this was the issue!